# for in loop in for statement inserting last form value

Tags: javascript, angular

**Requirements:**
I have question and answers forms where questions are dynamic, I have to send user selected answers to API. I should send data in below format.

```
"title" : "test title",
"clientId" : 1,
"categoryId" : 1,
"serviceId" : 1,
"steps" : [
  {
      "questionId" : "1",
      "question" : "what is your name",
      "answerId" : "1",
      "answer" : "John Doe"
  },
  {
      "questionId" : "2",
      "question" : "what is your age",
      "answerId" : "2",
      "answer" : "32"
  }
]
```

so I have questionId and question from API and answerId and answer from user input forms now I am trying to combine questions and answers in above format by looping through questions and answers like below:

```
var step = [];
var innerArray = {}
var QuestionsFormData = this.CreateServiceQuestionsForm.value;
    for (var i=0; i < this.getQuestionsData.length; i++){
        for(var key in this.CreateServiceQuestionsForm.controls) {
            if(this.CreateServiceQuestionsForm.controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(this.CreateServiceQuestionsForm.controls[key]);
                innerArray = {
                    "questionId"    : this.getQuestionsData[i].id,
                    "question"      : this.getQuestionsData[i].question,
                    "answerId"      : key,
                    "answer"        : this.CreateServiceQuestionsForm.controls[key].value,
                }
            }
        }
        step.push(innerArray);
    }
```

and this is what I am getting:

```
"steps" : [
  {
      "questionId" : "1",
      "question" : "what is your name",
      "answerId" : "5",
      "answer" : "you city is bla bla"
  },
  {
      "questionId" : "2",
      "question" : "what is your age",
      "answerId" : "5",
      "answer" : "your city is bla bla"
  },
  {
      "questionId" : "3",
      "question" : "what is your profession",
      "answerId" : "5",
      "answer" : "your city is bla bla"
  }
]
```

Note that I am getting same answerId ans answer in final object.
I am stuck and help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your `steps.push(innerArray)` needs to be one level of brackets deeper. Right now its only pushing one object for each question. It is *not* pushing a new `innerAray` object for each answer. It's only pushing the last `innerArray` value, because all the other ones are just being overwritten in the next iteration without being pushed on to the overall records array.

```
var step = [];
var innerArray = {}
var QuestionsFormData = this.CreateServiceQuestionsForm.value;
    for (var i=0; i < this.getQuestionsData.length; i++){
        for(var key in this.CreateServiceQuestionsForm.controls) {
            if(this.CreateServiceQuestionsForm.controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(this.CreateServiceQuestionsForm.controls[key]);
                innerArray = {
                    "questionId"    : this.getQuestionsData[i].id,
                    "question"      : this.getQuestionsData[i].question,
                    "answerId"      : key,
                    "answer"        : this.CreateServiceQuestionsForm.controls[key].value,
                }
            }
            step.push(innerArray) // < --- but it should be here
        }
        // < --- step.push(innerArray) is currently here
    }
```

Comment: What's the output after moving the statement?